The probability of each specific ordering of a group of independent uniform random variables
Given: A sequence of $n$ positive real numbers (the scales of the uniform random variables) $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n \in \mathbb R_{+}$
Let: $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ be mutually independent uniform randomly variables such that $x_i \sim t_i \times \operatorname{Unif}(0, 1), \forall i \in [n]$
To compute: The probability of each specific ordering of $x_i$'s, e.g., $\Pr[x_1 > x_2 > \cdots > x_n]$.

Thoughts: For $n = 2$, it would be easy.
$$\Pr[x_1 > x_2] = \int_{0}^{t_{\min}} \frac{t_1 - r_2}{t_1 t_2} dr_2 = \frac{t_{min}}{t_2} - \frac{t_{\min}^2}{2t_1 t_2} = 1 - \Pr[x_2 > x_1],$$
where $t_{\min} = \min(t_1, t_2)$.
Q: Do we have better ways to compute this, even closed-form?

A related (more general) question on MathOverflow without a clear answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267851
Another related question: Probability and expectation of three ordered random variables

The $t_i$ (along with $0$) divide $\Bbb R$ into intervals. You can compute the probability of a given ordering of the $x_i$ by splitting into cases corresponding to the ways to place the $x_i$ into the intervals. There are finitely many cases and the probability for each case is easy to compute (using symmetry when multiple RVs are placed in the same interval).

Thanks! I can see there are finitely many cases, but at first sight I think the number would be $n!$...

Well, every ordering is possible, so the distribution you're computing takes $n!$ time just to write down. For a given ordering, the number of cases to consider (using the approach I suggested) is at most $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ because the assignment of variables to intervals has to be consistent with the ordering.
